# Better to have an antenna outdoors but low, or indoors but high?

Tags: antenna

I am locating an antenna and I have the option of putting indoors on the second floor or outdoors on a deck where it will be 15 feet lower.

The house is wood frame with gypsum walls.

Will the attenuation of the walls be significant, or am I better off putting the antenna indoors?

Comment: How far are you from the stations you want to receive?

Comment: this depends on the antenna, the wavelength (or frequency), your surroundings, the direction of the thing you want to receive or transmit to! You know all this, honestly, this is not your first contact with antennas :)

Answer (score 1):

More details are needed to give an answer for your specific situation, but if you think in terms of wavelength, you can derive rule of thumb:

AM broadcast (LF): the height difference and the wall thickness are both tiny compared to the wavelength; probably no difference between locations.

FM broadcast (VHF): the height difference is on the order of a wavelength, the wall thickness isn't.  I'd choose the higher location.

TV and cell phones (UHF):  unfortunately, now it's a toss-up. A second floor facing a window in the direction of the other station is probably best.

WiFi, Bluetooth, other 2.4 and 5 GHz:  a wall is a significant fraction of a wavelength and will cause 10-30 dB of attenuation (i.e. a factor of 10 to 1000). As long as the other station is within line-of-sight from your deck, I'd choose the outdoor location. But if the station's in the other direction and your house would block it, use the indoor room closest to the station's direction.

Answer (score 0):

**For FTA TV antenna the most important aspect is free of blockage** from buildings or trees as the moisture in leaves make great reflectors as well as other buildings.  Attic roofs are commonly used but **I would initially use it outside** and measure the signal with some tools by manual rotation.  I have diagnostic software for my digital tuner to do this. I used Teamviewer to watch the indoor TV on my iPad remotely outside.

Height is less important 1~2 dB improvement to roof 20m, but aim thru a neighbours tree above their roof and lose -10 ~ -15 dB easily.

For example I am slightly north of Toronto and I have a Bowtie Yagi antenna on my chimney, aimed SSE towards Buffalo by aiming slightly away from the CNTower,  S of me in Toronto, which might saturate my pre-amp and cause dropouts on weak channels from IM distortion. ( CN Tower is a 553.3 m-high concrete communications and observation tower )  I have a high gain Bowtie antenna and a HDHomerun digital tuner connected to a router.   **This gives me a 100 mile range.**

[image]

For example I do hve some trees on my neighbours property blocking my signal and its worse in Winter with snow, but perfect after the snow melts. Channel 2 can be hit or miss at 96 miles.  But by tuning 0.1 deg for max signal, I can get it.

Check your signal levels here https://www.overtheairdigitaltv.com/tv-station-locator-tool/
also https://www.tvfool.com/